# Filtering sequence based on custom types using `protocols`, but getting error

Tags: swift

Here I'm trying to find the solution to reuse the filter options based on the account type,
But, I'm getting errors like *Protocol 'Selectable' as a type that cannot conform to the protocol itself.*

Here I'm getting 3 Account types `Savings`, `CreditCard`, `Beneficiary` now I would like to filter based on filter types like only `Beneficiary` or `Savings & CreditCard`.

Here is my sample code.

```swift
protocol Selectable { }

struct CreditCard: Selectable {
    var name: String
    var number: String
    var type = "creditCard"
    
}

struct Savings: Selectable {
    var name: String
    var number: String
    var type = "savingsAccount"

}

struct Beneficiary: Selectable {
    var name: String
    var number: String
    var type = "benefeciary"
}

let productSummary : [Selectable]  = [
    Savings(name: "S1", number: "1"),
    Savings(name: "S2", number: "2"),
    CreditCard(name: "C1", number: "3"),
    CreditCard(name: "C2", number: "4"),
    Beneficiary(name: "B1", number: "5"),
    Beneficiary(name: "B2", number: "6")
]


extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Selectable {
    func fetch(type: AccountFiter) -> [Selectable] {
        switch type {
        case .beneficiaries:
            return self.filter { (item) -> Bool in
                return item is Benefeciary
            }
            
        case .accounts:
            return self.filter { (item) -> Bool in
                return item is CreditCard || item is Savings
            }
        }
    }
}

enum AccountFiter {
    case beneficiaries
    case accounts
}


// Fetch only beneficiaries
let accounts = productSummary.fetch(type: .beneficiaries)
// Fetch only own accounts
let beneficiaries = productSummary.fetch(type: .accounts)
print("ac", accounts)
print("bc", beneficiaries)
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An array of a protocol type is a really bad idea. As the error tells you, it's not really a type; a protocol cannot conform to itself. And the whole idea of struct types distinguished by a string tag is downright horrifying. It could be good to rethink this architecture.

Comment: Since all three structs have the same attributes why not merge them into _one_ struct with an enum attribute that holds the type?

Comment: Take a look at this question which has the same case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself